# onNodeChange in tinymce v5?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

i added a external plugin in tinymce ( https://moodle.org/plugins/tinymce_glatex )

i add it in tinymce.init like this

```html
plugins: ['glatex'],
toolbar: ' glatex',
external_plugins: {
  'glatex': '/images/glatex/tinymce/editor_plugin.js'
},
```

but there is a error in console

```html
Failed to initialize plugin: glatex TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at t.<computed>.t.<computed>.init (editor_plugin.js:48)
    at cN (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at Object.ge [as each] (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at pN (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at EE.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at ge (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at u (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at tinymce.min.js:2
    
theme.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Errors: 
Failed path: (toolbarbutton)
Could not find valid *strict* value for "onAction" in {
  "title": "LaTeX Plugin",
  "cmd": "LatexPlugin",
  "image": "/images/glatex/tinymce/img/latex.png",
  "type": "button"
}

Input object: {
  "title": "LaTeX Plugin",
  "cmd": "LatexPlugin",
  "image": "/images/glatex/tinymce/img/latex.png",
  "type": "button"
}
    at theme.min.js:2
    at Object.getOrDie (theme.min.js:2)
    at theme.min.js:2
    at theme.min.js:2
    at Object.fold (theme.min.js:2)
    at theme.min.js:2
    at Object.fold (theme.min.js:2)
    at qE (theme.min.js:2)
    at theme.min.js:2
    at V (theme.min.js:2)
```

and this is the code of the editor_plugin.js in glatex

```html
(function () {

        tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.LatexPlugin', {

          
    init: function (ed, url) {
      ed.addCommand('LatexPlugin', function () {
          ed.windowManager.open({
              file: ed.getParam("moodle_plugin_base") + 'glatex/glatex.php',
              width: 640 + parseInt(ed.getLang('latex.delta_width', 0)),
              height: 480 + parseInt(ed.getLang('latex.delta_height', 0)),
              inline: 1
          }, {
              plugin_url: url
          });
      });

      // Register button
      ed.ui.registry.addButton('glatex', {
          title: 'LaTeX Plugin',
          cmd: 'LatexPlugin',
          image: url + '/img/latex.png'
      });

      // Node change events
      ed.onNodeChange.add(function (ed, cm, n) {
          cm.setActive('glatex', n.nodeName == 'IMG');
      });

    },

    getInfo: function () {
        return {
            longname: 'Latex plugin',
            author: 'Diego Caponera',
            authorurl: 'http://www.diegocaponera.com',
            infourl: 'http://www.diegocaponera.com',
            version: "1.0"
        };
    }
    });

// Register plugin
       tinymce.PluginManager.add('glatex', tinymce.plugins.LatexPlugin)
})();
```

**is there anyone understand this error ?** i have searching it entire time but there is no solution found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you are referencing appears to have been written prior to the release of TinyMCE 5 so it likely uses TinyMCE 4's APIs.

In order for the plugin to work with TinyMCE 5 it would need to be updated to work with TinyMCE 5's APIs.

There is documentation on migrating from TinyMCE 4 to 5 here:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/migration-from-4x